# Sources for connection between Succah and Chuppah

Tags: sources-mekorot, sukkah, chupah

I can see many things in common, they both relate to the story of the Exodus - G-d seated the Israelites in Succos and Matan Torah was sort of a Chuppah something, both have 4 bars and a feeble roof, both are temporary and largely symbolic.

However, I see no mentioning of one by the other - no mentioning of a Chuppah in Succos obligatory recitements, and no mentioning of a Succah in the wedding procedure.

Are there sources that link between the two?

Comment: +1 My father gave a very nice speech on this at my sister’s vort. I’ll B”N ask him for his notes and write them up as an answer.

Comment: You know a sukkah built like a chuppah  is pasul, right? https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.630.6?lang=bi

Comment: @JoelK It's a Machlokes, but some think that it's OK. I'm not looking for Halachic similarities, as I wrote, but theoretical, metaphorical if you want.

Comment: +1 I understand your question and am looking forward to the answer.

Comment: @AlBerko Who thinks it's ok (without positioning it on top of a roof and using גוד אסיק)?

Answer (score 2):

It's in Gemara at the beginning of Sukkah:

> **מנה"מ** אמר רבה דאמר קרא (ויקרא כג, מג) למען ידעו דורותיכם כי בסוכות הושבתי את בני ישראל עד עשרים אמה אדם יודע שהוא דר בסוכה למעלה מעשרים אמה אין אדם יודע שדר בסוכה משום דלא שלטא בה עינא **רבי זירא אמר מהכא (ישעיהו ד, ו) וסוכה תהיה לצל יומם מחורב** עד עשרים אמה אדם יושב בצל סוכה למעלה מעשרים אמה אין אדם יושב בצל סוכה אלא בצל דפנות א"ל אביי אלא מעתה העושה סוכתו בעשתרות קרנים הכי נמי דלא הוי סוכה א"ל התם דל עשתרות קרנים איכא צל סוכה הכא דל דפנות ליכא צל סוכה ורבא אמר מהכא (ויקרא כג, מב) בסוכות תשבו שבעת ימים אמרה תורה כל שבעת הימים צא מדירת קבע ושב בדירת עראי עד עשרים אמה אדם עושה דירתו דירת עראי למעלה מעשרים אמה אין אדם עושה דירתו דירת עראי אלא דירת קבע א"ל אביי אלא מעתה עשה מחיצות של ברזל וסיכך על גבן הכי נמי דלא הוי סוכה א"ל הכי קאמינא לך עד כ' אמה דאדם עושה דירתו דירת עראי כי עביד ליה דירת קבע נמי נפיק למעלה מכ' אמה דאדם עושה דירתו דירת קבע כי עביד ליה דירת עראי נמי לא נפיק
>   כולהו כרבה לא אמרי ההוא ידיעה לדורות היא **כרבי זירא נמי לא אמרי ההוא לימות המשיח הוא דכתיב ור' זירא א"כ לימא קרא וחופה תהיה לצל יומם ומאי וסוכה תהיה לצל יומם שמעת מינה תרתי** כרבא נמי לא אמרי משום קושיא דאביי
>
> How do we know that a sukkah can't be bigger than 20 amos? ... Rabbi Zeira says, from the pasuk "And a sukkah will provide shade during the day" ... The other amoraim don't say like R' Zeira because that pasuk is talking about in the days of Mashiach, not about a normal sukkah.  But R' Zeira says, in that case it should just say וחופה.  Since it says וסוכה, that gives us a halacha about sukkah.

To strengthen it a bit, look at that pasuk with a little context:

> וּבָרָ֣א יְהוָ֡ה עַל֩ כָּל־מְכ֨וֹן הַר־צִיּ֜וֹן וְעַל־מִקְרָאֶ֗הָ עָנָ֤ן ׀ יוֹמָם֙ וְעָשָׁ֔ן וְנֹ֛גַהּ אֵ֥שׁ לֶהָבָ֖ה לָ֑יְלָה כִּ֥י עַל־כָּל־כָּב֖וֹד **חֻפָּֽה**׃
>   **וְסֻכָּ֛ה** תִּהְיֶ֥ה לְצֵל־יוֹמָ֖ם מֵחֹ֑רֶב וּלְמַחְסֶה֙ וּלְמִסְתּ֔וֹר מִזֶּ֖רֶם וּמִמָּטָֽר׃

Comment: Sorry, You probably misunderstood the question. This gemmora simply plays with the two words, but makes no connection between the two. I asked about the "metaphorical" connection between the two ideas.

Comment: @AlBerko what about the text that tells you that it is not making a connection between a chupah and a sukkah? That these two were mentioned together side-by-side appears to suggest a connection.

Comment: @ninamag What about it? Yes they are mentioned, yes some connection is implied, but nothing more - it does not answer - what the connection is.

Comment: @alberko You didn't ask what the connection is.  You ask for sources for a connection.

Comment: OK you won.  ......

Answer (score 2):

There is an idea from the Ramban (Vayikra 23:43) which links the words of sukkah and chuppah. I believe the idea is that a sukkah and chuppah both show a closeness and protective environment. With regards to sukkah we had such a protection from Hashem. By chuppah it is the man who is bringing his wife into his chuppah as a resemblance of closeness and protective element. The Ramban brings the passuk of Yeshayahu 4:5 which describes the chuppah(ananai hakavod type description - which is what sukkah was according to one opinion.)

**Text of Ramban (English translation courtesy of Sefaria):**

"I made the Israelite people live in booths. Rashi's comment seems to me to be the straightforward sense of the verse. He has commanded that all future generations should know the deeds of the great God "Who dealt so wondrously with you" (Joel 2:26) sheltering them under the clouds of His Presence as in a booth. **Having already explained that "over the Tabernacle a cloud of the LORD rested by day, and fire would appear in it by night" (Exodus 40:38), our verse needed only to say, "I made the Israelite people live in booths" - "I made My Presence into clouds of glory as shelters to protect them." We find the same notion in Isaiah 4:5-6, "The LORD will create over the whole shrine and meeting place of Mount Zion cloud by day and smoke with a glow of flaming fire by night. Indeed, over all the glory shall hand a canopy, which shall serve as a pavilion for shade from heat by day and as a shelter for protection against drenching rain.**" At the beginning of the dry season, we are commanded to remember the exodus by making Nisan the first month of the year, and by celebrating the festival of Passover; here, at the beginning of the rainy season, a further observance is commanded, in commemoration of the ongoing miracle that was done for them throughout their 40 years in the wilderness. According to the opinion that the phrase refers to actual booths, they did begin making them at the start of the rainy season because of the cold, as people do when they camp, and that is why our text commands that booths be made at this season. In that case, what the future generations are supposed to know is that they made their way in the wilderness and "found no settled place" (Psalms 107:4) for 40 years. But God was with them, and they "lacked nothing" (Deuteronomy 2:7)."

**Text of Ramban in Hebrew (Sefaria):**

**כי בסכות הושבתי את בני ישראל ענני כבוד לשון רש"י והוא הנכון בעיני על דרך הפשט כי צוה שידעו הדורות את כל מעשי ה' הגדול אשר עשה עמהם להפליא ששכן אותם בענני כבודו כסוכה כענין שנאמר (ישעיה ד ה ו) וברא ה' על כל מכון הר ציון ועל מקראיה ענן יומם ועשן ונגה אש להבה לילה כי על כל כבוד חפה וסוכה תהיה לצל יומם מחרב וגו' ומפני שכבר פירש שענן ה' עליהם יומם ועמוד האש בלילה** אמר סתם כי בסכות הושבתי שעשיתי להם ענני כבודי סכות להגן עליהם והנה צוה בתחילת ימות החמה בזכרון יציאת מצרים בחדשו ובמועדו וצוה בזכרון הנס הקיים הנעשה להם כל ימי עמידתם במדבר בתחלת ימות הגשמים ועל דעת האומר סכות ממש עשו להם (סוכה יא) החלו לעשותן בתחילת החרף מפני הקור כמנהג המחנות ולכן צוה בהן בזמן הזה והזכרון שידעו ויזכרו שהיו במדבר לא באו בבית ועיר מושב לא מצאו ארבעים שנה והשם היה עמהם לא חסרו דבר

Comment: what is an "ananai hakavod type description"?